# Error when doing a condition with a boolean = null

Tags: java, null, boolean

I get an error on Eclipse when i try this code

```
boolean notif = (Boolean) null;
if(notif == null) // <== ERROR at this line saying "No suggestion available" (very helpful)
 {
    System.out.println("Notif = null");
 }
```

Why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boolean` is a primitive type, it only accepts `true` or `false`. If you want to assign `null` to your variable, use the object `Boolean` instead.

```
Boolean notif = null;

if(notif == null) {
    System.out.println("Notif = null");
}
```

But... if you're using the primitive type, do this:

```
boolean notif = // true or false;

if(notif) {
    System.out.println("Notif = true");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Notif = false");
}
```

**EDIT:** The difference between `Boolean` and `boolean` is that the first one is an object, and it comes with some methods you might want to use. The second one, as a primitive type uses less memory. Now consider those points and choose what you need ;)

More on `Boolean` object [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) on the docs.

Comment: Haha! My bad. Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V fault ;) Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help dude, I didn't even know that Boolean object existed.

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad to help. Don't forget to upvote it and mark as accepted if it was useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

> boolean can't be null. It can either be true or false

```
boolean notif = false;

if(notif)
{
  System.out.println("notif is true");
}
else
{
 System.out.println("notif is false");
}
```

while the Object `Boolean` can be.

Answer (score 2):

When you casting null to "Boolean it's wrapper class not the primitive boolean. but when you are comparing you are comparing with the primitive boolean which expects value only true or false not null.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the value of all null in the primitive datatype, 
instead you should use Boolean class which can be null and suits your type of implementation.

```
Boolean notif =  null;
  if( notif == null ) {
      System.out.println("notif is null");
    }  else {
    if(notif){
      System.out.println("notif is true");
    } else {
      System.out.println("notif is false");
    }
}
```